# Fade in/out a stack panel on top of a mediaElement (both are within the same cell in a grid)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and I am facing an issue in this. I am making a simple video application, and the application has 3 columns. The 2nd column is a gridsplitter, and the **3rd column** is a **MediaElement** and a **StackPanel (containing video controls)** on top of it.

The thing I want to achieve is to fade in the StackPanel when the mouse pointer enters the MediaElement, and fade out the StackPanel when the mouse pointer exits the MediaElement. However, the problem occurs when the mouse pointer enters the StackPanel, which will trigger the fade out effect (MouseExit event of the MediaElement will occur).

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_learningapp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:WPF_learningapp"
    Title="MiDrama" Height="350" Width="700" ResizeMode="CanResize">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Custom assets/CustomScrollbar.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <MyNamespace:PausePlayBooleanConverter x:Key="PausePlayBooleanConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<MyNamespace:GridControl>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="0" MaxWidth="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width= "*">
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <MediaElement Grid.Column="2" Name="myMediaPlayer" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill">
        <MediaElement.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
             <BeginStoryboard>
                 <Storyboard>
                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControlPanel"
                             From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                 </Storyboard>
             </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
             <BeginStoryboard>
                 <Storyboard>
                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"           Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControlPanel"
                            From="1.0" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                 </Storyboard>
             </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
       </MediaElement.Triggers>
    </MediaElement>
    <StackPanel Name="VideoControlPanel" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="59" Margin="55,0,41,4" Background="Transparent">
        <Slider Name="VideoSlider" Thumb.DragStarted="slider_DragStarted"  Thumb.DragCompleted="slider_DragCompleted" Margin="0,0,0,5"
                IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged"/>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=isPlaying, Converter={StaticResource PausePlayBooleanConverter}}" Height="34" Width="50" Margin="5 0" Name="playpause_Btn" Click="playpause_Btn_Click"/>
            <Button Height="34" Width="50" Content="Stop" Margin="5 0" Name="stop_Btn" Click="stop_Btn_Click"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</MyNamespace:GridControl>
```

I tried encapsulating everything in a canvas within the grid, but the control panel will not resize properly. Even implementing an event trigger on the grid column doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to accomplish this? Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you should place the EventTrigger for MouseLeave on the StackPanel or maybe on the content of the StackPanel - not on the MediaElement.

**EDIT**

OK, I thought the stackpanel was covering the whole medialelement (I didn't see the height prop).

A solution could be to place the mediaelement and the stackpanel inside a content control of some kind as in the below example:

```
<Window x:Class="SO40188046.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO40188046"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Border Background="Blue">
    <Border.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControlPanel" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControlPanel" From="1.0" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
    <Grid>
      <MediaElement Source="SOME MEDIA URI" />
      <Border Name="VideoControlPanel" Background="Red" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0" />
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</Window>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here I have modfied you own answer so no code behind is needed to size and position the controls. I've replaced Canvas with a ContentControl and replaced some other controls too. But the overall layout is the same:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_learningapp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:WPF_learningapp"
        Title="MiDrama" Height="350" Width="700" ResizeMode="CanResize">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Custom assets/CustomScrollbar.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <MyNamespace:PausePlayBooleanConverter x:Key="PausePlayBooleanConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="0" MaxWidth="300"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width= "*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="2" Background="AliceBlue">
      <ContentControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControlPanel"
                From="0.0" 
                To="1.0" 
                Duration="0:0:1"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControlPanel"
                From="1.0" 
                To="0" 
                Duration="0:0:1"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </ContentControl.Triggers>
      <Grid>
        <MediaElement 
          Name="myMediaPlayer" 
          Stretch="Fill"  />
        <Grid Name="VideoControlPanel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="60" Background="Transparent" Opacity="0">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Slider 
            Name="VideoSlider" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Thumb.DragStarted="slider_DragStarted"  
            Thumb.DragCompleted="slider_DragCompleted" 
            Margin="10,5"
            IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" 
            ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged"/>
          <Button 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Content="Play" 
            Height="26" 
            Width="50" 
            Name="playpause_Btn" 
            Click="playpause_Btn_Click"/>
          <Button 
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="26" 
            Width="50"
            Content="Stop"
            Name="stop_Btn" 
            Click="stop_Btn_Click"/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I can't do that, the StackPanel is just a small part inside the grid and I want it to appear once I enter the grid.The only Control that covers the entire grid is the MediaElement.

Comment: ?? Who are and Why are you downwoting?

Comment: I have updated my xaml code. I don't think drawing a border would work, I need the animation to be,

1. Mouse enter 3rd column, display StackPanel.
2. Mouse exits 3rd column, remove StackPanel.

Comment: @Ytan: But the border is just an example of a content control. You can for instance copy all my code from <Border... /Border> and put it in you third column and change Border to ContentControl or what ever you want, and it will work the way you describe... You have to think for your self along the path of our answer or else it not worth the trouble :-)

Comment: I see, finally I just encapsulated everything in the third column inside a canvas, and manually resize everything inside. I thought there would be a simpler alternative. I have updated my UI xaml as well.

Comment: @Ytan: Glad you found a solution. But I'm quite sure that it can be done simpler - in pure xaml - than you describe. You could post your solution as an answer, then I can comment on that.

Comment: Updated the final solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the issue above. Put everything inside a canvas within a grid cell (which I think is the only container that is easy to work with overlapping controls).

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_learningapp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:WPF_learningapp"
        Title="MiDrama" Height="350" Width="700" ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Custom assets/CustomScrollbar.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <MyNamespace:PausePlayBooleanConverter x:Key="PausePlayBooleanConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <MyNamespace:GridControl>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="0" MaxWidth="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width= "*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Canvas Grid.Column="2" Name="VideoCanvas" SizeChanged="VideoCanvas_sizeChanged" Background="AliceBlue">
            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControlPanel"
                             From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControlPanel"
                            From="1.0" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
            <MediaElement Grid.Column="2" Name="myMediaPlayer" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=VideoCanvas}"  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=VideoCanvas}"/>
            <StackPanel Name="VideoControlPanel" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="59" Background="Transparent" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="250" Width="371">
                <Slider Name="VideoSlider" Thumb.DragStarted="slider_DragStarted"  Thumb.DragCompleted="slider_DragCompleted" Margin="0,0,0,5"
                    IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged"/>
                <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Path=isPlaying, Converter={StaticResource PausePlayBooleanConverter}}" Height="34" Width="50" Margin="5 0" Name="playpause_Btn" Click="playpause_Btn_Click"/>
                    <Button Height="34" Width="50" Content="Stop" Margin="5 0" Name="stop_Btn" Click="stop_Btn_Click"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
    </MyNamespace:GridControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: See my **EDIT 2** in my answer.